# Error opening files read from socket

Tags: java, sockets, io

I have a simple pair of client / server FTP classes using TCP protocol. I'm able to transfer small text files, but when I try a larger file like [this](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~foster/dictionary.txt), the file appears corrupted (editors are locked up trying to open it, less gets stuck jumping to the end.) I have a feeling I'm not closing it correctly, or reading and saving it correctly from the socket. Here are both get() functions from client and server. Hopefully someone can catch what I'm doing wrong.

Server:

```
public void get(){

    // get file path from client
    try {
        this.filePath = controlIn.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        controlOut.println(ERROR);
        dataOut.println("Server Error: Unable to read file path");
        System.out.println("error reading filepath");
        return;
    }   

    // if client sends 0, abort GET (file exists in client directory)
    if(filePath == "-1"){
        return;
    }       

    // check if file exists
    File f = new File(filePath);
    if(!f.exists()){
        controlOut.println(ERROR);
        dataOut.println("Server Error: File does not exist: " + filePath);
        return;
    }

    // send file size as success msg
    int fileSize = (int)f.length();
    controlOut.println(fileSize);

    //read file to buffer, write buffer to socket
    byte [] buf  = new byte [fileSize];

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(buf,0,buf.length);
        OutputStream os = dataSocket.getOutputStream();
        os.write(buf,0,fileSize);
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Client:

```
public void get(String filePath){

    // check if file exists. If not, send ERROR to server
    File f = new File(filePath);
    if(f.exists()){
        controlOut.println(ERROR);
        System.out.println("Client Error: File: " + filePath + " already exists");
        return;
    }

    // send file path to server
    controlOut.println(filePath);

    // read status from server. Status > 0 = file size
    int status = readStatus();  
    if(status == ERROR){
        System.out.println(readError());
        return;
    }

    int fileSize = status;
    int bytesRead;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;

    byte [] buf  = new byte [fileSize*2];
    try {
        InputStream is = dataSocket.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        do{
             bytesRead = is.read(buf,0,fileSize);
        } while(bytesRead != -1);
        bos.write(buf, 0 , fileSize);
        is.close();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

One more thing. The data socket is closed on the server side after the get method returns, and fileSize seems to be correct on the client side.

Comment: Could you do ls and get the file size that way?

Comment: If what you mean is for me to look at both files now, they're the same. Both are 3206080 bytes.

Comment: Your while loop is wrong (you're reading in a loop, but not writing inside the loop), and you don't need a huge buffer. 8192 bytes is plenty enough.

Answer (score -1):

File size is to big for an Integer

Honestly: just make it a loop like

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
   //do something with the buffer, eg:
   StringBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, len));
```

Comment: isn't maximum size for a java int  2,147,483,647? Seems big enough for this case.